# How to exclude .php file from .htaccess redirect(rewriteRule)?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to know how I can exclude a specific .php file from redirecting on a rewriteRule.

`site.com/images/resizer.php` keeps redirecting to `site.com/images/resizer/` and that's an issue as I have some headers that sets as followed ex: `site.com/images/resizer/?page=2`

In my .htaccess I have two rewrite rules that removes .php file extensions and forces slashes at the end of the url, and I'd like to exclude that resizer.php from being rewritten.

```
#if page with .php is requested then remove the extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

#Force a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+?[^/.])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

#silently rewrite to webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webroot/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

#.php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I'd like resizer to be as followed: `site.com/images/resizer.php?page=2`

I tried adding the following under both the slash and .php hide extension rule but it did not work, I'm completely stuck with this..

### failed attempts (under both rewriteRule)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/resizer$ [NC]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^images/resizer/?$ /images/resizer.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. In both of the redirect rules, add a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/resizer\.php
```

So:

```
#if page with .php is requested then remove the extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/resizer\.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

#Force a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/resizer\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+?[^/.])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I tried both instances, yet none worked. I also kept trying with others which did not workout very well. http://www.site.com/images/resizer.php?src=image.png keeps redirecting to http://www.site.com/images/resizer/?src=image.png but I will continue to try, report back soon.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to work.. any other ideas?:/ this is my whole .htaccess http://pastebin.com/jTfDe20S

Comment: @iBrazilian2 Dunno, the 2 rules above works for me, did you clear your browser's cache?